How to merge/join 2 rows after long columns were misread into separate rows?
My dataframe has 3 columns:

File-Name
Time Stamp
File Size

The read adds rows where the file-Name is too long. For each occurrence of this, I need to:

merge the two rows
remove the None and NaN values
finally remove the extra row.

Here I have row 20 and row 21. row 21 is the excess of the file-path and name:
20  ./.c9/dependencies/extensionHost/956a43f1ecc7f34424174768925cd9cc5a3e006d2ad71e6bd939f2a    2024-04-17 12:56    135268
21  None    NaN e04e9ef74933c4cab24ec0f62a973d0b06e59e466286a73382db011071887b5eafad4b8b9/package

Here is how it should look ...
And again another extra row was generated for row 74:
70  ./.nvm/versions/node/v20.12.0/include/node/ope...   2024-03-26 16:18    53440
71  ./.cache/node-gyp/18.19.0/include/node/openssl...   2024-03-06 19:24    53440
72  ./.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.1/include/node/ope...   2024-02-13 23:50    53440
73  ./.c9/node/include/node/openssl/archs   2023-11-29 14:59    53440
74  ./.c9/dependencies/node18-linux-x64/7e2ea6e5ed...   2023-11-29 14:59    53440
75  None    NaN 85de0311e77fec00f3ce2303de1affbe390e7b22b96402...

I'm trying to use merge or combine all the rows with NaN values.

Welcome to SO! I have suggested an edit to clarify your post. However it looks like you haven't specified "how it should look" (sentence was left incomplete). Consider adding that information. I suppose you want to concatenate the two parts of the string path, is that it?

Have you considered fixing the read method instead? What does the file that you eaad, look like?

the edit looks perfect.  yes, i hvae i believe, worked to a closer solution, but i'm not exactly sure how to complete the process.  this method will be used to format all kinds of messy data and these are the basic direct tools i should be able to utilize. i'm having trouble getting the filename to concat. everything i try seems to lose the data or rows.  thanks for the clarity in my format.

Is nothing from @ouroboros1 suggestions helping? That looked likea pretty sound answer, although maybe you would profit from more step by step suggestions.

Since you added a "partial solution" after I posted my answer, maybe your df is more complicated than my working sample suggests. If so (and in general), the best way to reach a solution is to update your question with a [mre]. E.g., use df.to_dict(), simplify the sample, and post between backticks (```), constructing a df as I've done in my answer. Add also the expected output based on that sample. If you have a specific issue with implementing my answer, please explain in a comment underneath. Maybe there's an easy fix.

superb solutions. very helpful. thank you.  very clear elegant.

Option 1 (always just one trailing erroneous row)
Minimal reproducible example
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'File-Name': {0: 'file', 1: None, 2: 'file2', 3: 'file', 4: None}, 
         'Time Stamp': {0: '2024-01-01 00:00:00', 1: np.nan, 2: '2024-01-01 00:00:00', 
                       3: '2024-01-01 00:00:00', 4: np.nan}, 
         'File Size': {0: 1, 1: '1_too_long', 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: '3_too_long'}
         }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df

  File-Name           Time Stamp   File Size
0      file  2024-01-01 00:00:00           1
1      None                  NaN  1_too_long
2     file2  2024-01-01 00:00:00           2
3      file  2024-01-01 00:00:00           3
4      None                  NaN  3_too_long

Code
out = (
    df.assign(**{'File-Name': (df['File-Name'] + (df['File Size']
                                                  .where(df['File-Name'].isna())
                                                  .shift(-1)
                                                  .fillna(''))
                               )
                 }
              )
    .dropna(subset='File-Name')
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)

Output
        File-Name           Time Stamp File Size
0  file1_too_long  2024-01-01 00:00:00         1
1           file2  2024-01-01 00:00:00         2
2  file3_too_long  2024-01-01 00:00:00         3

Explanation

Use Series.where for df['File Size'], checking condition Series.isna for df['File-Name'], and apply Series.shift with -1 to shift the strings that need to be added to df['File-Name'] one row back.
Add Series.fillna to convert NaN values to an empty string (''), add to df['File-Name'] and overwrite the original column via df.assign.
Now, get rid of the None rows with df.dropna on subset='File-Name', and df.reset_index for a new continuous index.


Option 2 (possibility of more than one trailing erroneous rows)
Option 1 won't work as desired if the file names are so long that there are multiple trailing rows. In this case, we can use df.groupby:
Sample
data2 = {'File-Name': {0: 'file', 1: None, 2: 'file2', 3: 'file', 4: None, 5: None}, 
         'Time Stamp': {0: '2024-01-01 00:00:00', 1: np.nan, 2: '2024-01-01 00:00:00', 
                       3: '2024-01-01 00:00:00', 4: np.nan, 5: np.nan}, 
         'File Size': {0: 1, 1: '1_too_long', 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: '3_way', 5: '_too_long'}
         }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

df2

  File-Name           Time Stamp   File Size
0      file  2024-01-01 00:00:00           1
1      None                  NaN  1_too_long
2     file2  2024-01-01 00:00:00           2
3      file  2024-01-01 00:00:00           3
4      None                  NaN       3_way # multiple rows
5      None                  NaN   _too_long # multiple rows

Code
gr = df2['File-Name'].notna().cumsum()

out2 = (
    df2.assign(**{'File-Name': df2['File-Name'].where(df2['File-Name'].notna(), 
                                                df2['File Size'])
                  }
               )
    .groupby(gr, as_index=False)
    .agg({'File-Name': lambda x: ''.join(x), 
          'Time Stamp': 'first', 
          'File Size': 'first'})
)

Output
            File-Name           Time Stamp File Size
0      file1_too_long  2024-01-01 00:00:00         1
1               file2  2024-01-01 00:00:00         2
2  file3_way_too_long  2024-01-01 00:00:00         3

Explanation

Use Series.notna with Series.cumsum to group rows that belong to one 'File-Name'.
Use Series.where on df2['File-Name']: keep value if notna, else get df2['File Size'] and overwrite original 'File-Name' column via assign.
Now, apply df.groupby, passing our groups (gr), and apply groupby.agg. For 'File-Name' we want a join. For 'Time Stamp' and 'File Size' simply get first.


your code worked perfectly ouroboros1.

i've come up with this as a working partial solution and have 2 dataframes. one with the truncated file-names, and the other, just the stub of file name: here is a list of rows 13-16 from df1 (15 is a missing index)

13  ./.c9/dependencies/node18-linux-x64 2024-03-06 19:27    166940
14  ./.c9/dependencies/node18-linux-x64/7e2ea6e5edddeede43c966070975591a581c4ae0792a9b1a8af6    2024-03-06 19:27    166936
16  ./.nvm/versions/node/v20.12.0   2024-03-29 19:09    153080 
and rows 14,18, 20 from df2

14  85de0311e77fec00f3ce2303de1affbe390e7b22b96402f66e9354a817ac84e6e0cd7eb74bd1
18  e04e9ef74933c4cab24ec0f62a973d0b06e59e466286a73382db011071887b5eafad4b8b9
20  e04e9ef74933c4cab24ec0f62a973d0b06e59e466286a73382db011071887b5eafad4b8b9/package

the first has roughly 800 rows, the 2nd had about 250. they have matching  index number for the rows. my code was pretty simple :
'''
drop_null_df = df.dropna()
null_rows = df.loc[df["File-Name:"].isnull()]
null_rows = null_rows.rename(index = lambda x: x - 1)
'''
i dropped and renamed columns leaving one column name "File-Name:" in the null_rows df.
i want to merge the stubbed filename string from null_rows 200 entries to the drop_null_df column "File-Name:" with it's 800 entries. both dataframes have identical numbered index.
